# rm -r inside Makefile not removing directory

Tags: bash, rm, make

I am trying to check a website with [html-proofer](https://github.com/gjtorikian/html-proofer) with a `Makefile` rule and delete a temporal folder when it ends.

To make this work I start a server in one console and in another one execute the following rule:

```
SHELL := /bin/bash
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
VIRTUALENV_BIN=~/.virtualenvs/example/bin
PYTHON=$(VIRTUALENV_BIN)/python
PIP=$(VIRTUALENV_BIN)/pip
MANAGE=$(PYTHON) workouts/manage.py

WGET=/usr/bin/wget
HTMLPROOFER=/usr/local/bin/htmlproofer
TEMP_DIR_HTMLPROOF=$(shell mktemp -d)
.ONESHELL:
htmlproofer:
    cd $(TEMP_DIR_HTMLPROOF)
    $(WGET) --recursive --html-extension --convert-links --domains localhost --no-parent localhost:8000
    - $(HTMLPROOFER) .
    echo $(TEMP_DIR_HTMLPROOF)
    cd ..
    rm -r $(TEMP_DIR_HTMLPROOF)
```

It creates a temporal folder, download the entire website, performs the check with html-proofer and lastly tries to delete the temporal folder. For some reason I am unable to delete the folder.

I've tried even with `rm -rf` without luck, the temporal folder is always there (but with no contents), e.g.:

Suppose the temporal folder created is named: `/tmp/tmp.l21wiSkYdz`, then after running the `wget` command it will contain the downloaded website as `/tmp/tmp.l21wiSkYdz/localhost+8000`, but after the `rm` it will still be there as an empty folder: `/tmp/tmp.l21wiSkYdz`.

The only way I made it work was with an interactive usage of `rm` like: `rm -ir`.

Any ideas to completely remove the temporal folder or why it can be avoiding to delete it?

Some notes:

- `.ONESHELL:` executes each line in same subshell
- the dash before `html-proofer` makes it ignore the possible exit of the script without removing the temporal folder
- using *bash* `SHELL := /bin/bash`

Comment: Use := for variable assignments rather than the plain vanilla =. Why? Coz the plain assignment is like a subroutine , will be executed each time it is used. IOW, you are deleting a dir which is already empty and freshly created.

Comment: @RakeshSharma That was it, using the immediate assignment works, if you can put that as an answer I would gladly accept it.

Comment: Not in front of terminal, so will not be able to put up an answer section right now.Maybe you could, construct an answer for this will be good for future users.

Comment: @RakeshSharma ok, I created a *community wiki* with your comment, thanks ;)

Answer (score 2):

As @RakeshSharma pointed out in comments, I was using variable assignment with a single `=`, so it was deferred to execution time, executing it twice.

The second time the script tried to access the variable, it was executed again and created another temporal folder.

Changing `=` with `:=` makes it use the *immediate* expansion, so it creates the temporal folder once.

From

```
TEMP_DIR_HTMLPROOF=$(shell mktemp -d)
```

to this

```
TEMP_DIR_HTMLPROOF:=$(shell mktemp -d)
```

Answer (score 0):

The first problem I see.

you have as your commands

```
cd somewhere
do something
```

make creates a new shell for each line. So it will create a shell, change this shells present working directory, close the shell, create a new shell, and do something. This is now what you want.

you need to do

```
cd somewhere; do something
```

i.e.

```
htmlproofer:
    cd $(TEMP_DIR_HTMLPROOF); $(WGET) --recursive --html-extension --convert-links --domains localhost --no-parent localhost:8000 - $(HTMLPROOFER) . ;echo $(TEMP_DIR_HTMLPROOF)
    rm -r $(TEMP_DIR_HTMLPROOF)
```

---

note `cd ..` would do the wrong thing (in a shell script), but here does nothing (see above), and is not needed (see above). In a shell script `cd -` would be what you were trying to do, though pushd and popd are better.

Comment: > If .ONESHELL is mentioned as a target, then when a target is built all lines of the recipe will be given to a single invocation of the shell rather than each line being invoked separately